# how to get single result in using 2 table data

Tags: mysql, sql

i have to table 2 in same structure .i already get the result by using one table using following query

```
SELECT *,COUNT(Time), 
             CASE WHEN COUNT(Time) = 1 
                 THEN CASE WHEN Time > '00:00:00' && Time <= '12:15:00' 
                 THEN Time END ELSE MIN(Time) 
                 END as time_in, 
                 CASE WHEN COUNT(Time) = 1 
                     THEN CASE WHEN Time > '12:15:00' && Time <= '23:59:59' 
                     THEN Time END ELSE NULLIF(MAX(Time), MIN(Time)) 
                     END as time_out 
                 FROM attendancedata 
                 INNER JOIN nonacadamic 
                 ON attendancedata.EnrolledID = nonacadamic.emp_id 
                 WHERE nonacadamic.emp_id = '".$_POST["emp_id"]."' AND Date LIKE '$currentMonth%' 
                 GROUP BY EnrolledID,Date
```

this query will time devide in to the 2 part(time in and time out) .it work fine.now want to get the data from anther table also.it also have same structure  `attendancedata` table.

**attendancedata table structure**

```
EnrolledID  Date    Time    
23  2019-09-09  16:19:00    
53  2019-08-27  08:19:00
```

**tempattendancedata table structure**

```
EnrolledID  Date    Time    
23  2019-09-09  16:19:00    
23  2019-09-20  08:19:00
```

i want get the result consider above table record and then split time in to the two part .how can i do this task? **actual requirement is tempattendancedata table data also need considering for the time split**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you include the results of your temp table using `UNION ALL` then, put it in a `subquery` for your `select case` statement

```
SELECT *,COUNT(Time)
    ,CASE WHEN COUNT(Time) = 1 THEN 
        CASE WHEN Time > '00:00:00' && Time <= '12:15:00' 
            THEN Time END ELSE MIN(Time) 
    END as time_in, 
    CASE WHEN COUNT(Time) = 1 THEN 
        CASE WHEN Time > '12:15:00' && Time <= '23:59:59' 
            THEN Time END ELSE NULLIF(MAX(Time), MIN(Time)) 
    END as time_out 
FROM
    (SELECT *
    FROM attendancedata 
    INNER JOIN nonacadamic 
    ON attendancedata.EnrolledID = nonacadamic.emp_id 
    WHERE nonacadamic.emp_id = '".$_POST["emp_id"]."' AND Date LIKE '$currentMonth%'    
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM tempattendancedata 
    INNER JOIN nonacadamic 
    ON attendancedata.EnrolledID = nonacadamic.emp_id 
    WHERE nonacadamic.emp_id = '".$_POST["emp_id"]."' AND Date LIKE '$currentMonth%') t1
GROUP BY t1.EnrolledID, t1.Date
```

Comment: it is not working bro.but you get correct idea to me.thank you

Comment: replace * to your actual columns

Comment: that's just a typo

Comment: thank bro its working find.thank you very much your contribution